# rxJava how to make flatMap run on multi threads

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java3

I want every item emitted from flatMap to run on its own thread
This is a simplified example of a real usage where each item will be a url request.
Adding subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) on each single still run on a single thread
What's the rule here?

```java
Integer[] array= new Integer[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    array[i] = i+1;
}

Observable.fromArray(array)
        .flatMapSingle(new Function<Integer, SingleSource<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public SingleSource<Integer> apply(Integer i) throws Throwable {
                Log.i(TAG, "apply " +  i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return Single.just(i).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
        .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Integer i) {
               // Log.i(TAG, "onNext " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        });
```

Result:

```
2020-12-16 22:54:47.010 10649-10700/com.example.rxjava I/MYTAG: apply 1 RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2020-12-16 22:54:47.037 10649-10700/com.example.rxjava I/MYTAG: apply 2 RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2020-12-16 22:54:47.038 10649-10700/com.example.rxjava I/MYTAG: apply 3 RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2020-12-16 22:54:47.039 10649-10700/com.example.rxjava I/MYTAG: apply 4 RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2020-12-16 22:54:47.040 10649-10700/com.example.rxjava I/MYTAG: apply 5 RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2020-12-16 22:54:47.043 10649-10700/com.example.rxjava I/MYTAG: apply 6 RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2020-12-16 22:54:47.051 10649-10700/com.example.rxjava I/MYTAG: apply 7 RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2020-12-16 22:54:47.051 10649-10700/com.example.rxjava I/MYTAG: apply 8 RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
```

Comment: I don't really remember how RxJava works, but what I seem to see are: * your `flatMapSingle` always runs on the same thread, because the `Observable.fromArray` result is not told to do not so; * you seem not to need `flatMapSingle` at all; * not sure, but subscribing on `Schedulers.newThread()` or even `Schedulers.from(executor)` would do the job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading multiple image to AWS server using rxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65327820/uploading-multiple-image-to-aws-server-using-rxjava)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track except the use of `just`, which takes an **existing** object thus whatever created and computed that object happened before. In this case, it was the lambda of the `flatMapSingle` which is called from the same thread.

You have to make the computation itself part of the flow to be run in parallel via `fromCallable` for example:

```java
Observable.fromArray(array)
.flatMapSingle(i -> {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        Log.i(TAG, "apply " +  i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return i + 1000;
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
// ...
;
```

Comment: I have searched for this all day. Really appreciate!!